# Did I make the good choice by using present perfect

Tags: present-perfect

I bought a book through mail order and the seller sent me an email asking me if the address he had was  good and this is my answer

If you could write 750000  instead of 750010 it would be better but don't be afraid  it will arrive correctly whatever number you **have written**

I chose present perfect because I  did not know (still don't know) if he had  already written the address at the time I wrote  my reply. What do you think of my choice , is it a good one

Comment: The most important thing for most learners to know about Perfect verb forms is ***don't overuse them**!* In fact, *avoid* them wherever possible. I think the problem here is that "the rules" defining contexts in which Perfect forms *could* be used seem reasonably simple, so TELF teachers are too keen to drum those rules into their students, and the students are then excessively keen to actually *apply* their new-found knowledge about where to use Perfect forms. But in reality, native Anglophones naturally tend to use the simplest verb form possible in any given context (which ain't Perfect! :)

Comment: Idiomatically, it's ***don't worry*** here, not ***don't be afraid***.

Answer (score 1):

You might say *whichever number you write/use*. The plain form of the verb works for general statements, and this question doesn't seem to depend on a particular time of use/writing.
Also, if they are asking about the correct address, they probably haven't already sent the book.

Comment: i don't understand why you said it is a general statement it  relies on a particular time (the time before he wrote the address)

Comment: @user5577 The statement *it will arrive correctly whichever number you use* is always true, isn't it? There's no need to complicate that with a verb with tense.